# how to reset symfony2 cached routes inside controller?

Tags: caching, routes, symfony

I want to add routes dynamically. I am storing tree of documents in database. Based on document's position in that tree i can generate url for specific document. Problem is, whenever I add document to that tree, I have to clean cache because url matcher is precached. But if I clean cache inside controller by deleting of content of cache directory error is thrown. Is there any way, how to solve it?

more problem specification:

I need more routes to create, because based on documents type, its called specific controller and action (even with specific parameters). In tree item entity i store url_part and some parameters to create particular route (like controller and action), then parameters, which are passed to that controller. Entity has method getRoute() which knows how to build route from its data. Then i have for example page document, it is entity called page and it has relation to tree item (i did not wanted to mess with inheritance). When i create page, it knows how to fill data for related tree item. Problem is, when i create page, its not unvalidated cache with existing routes. I wanna have routes cached, so after creating page i wanna reset cached routes.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to generate routes dynamically? Can't you create a single route with a pattern which allows slashes?

I've made a similar CMS using Symfony2 before, and I used [StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) (have a look at `Tree` and `Sluggable`).

My `Document` entity had the following fields to support tree structure:

```
/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
 * @ORM\Column(name="`left`", type="integer")
 */
private $left;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
 * @ORM\Column(name="level", type="integer")
 */
private $level;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeRight
 * @ORM\Column(name="`right`", type="integer")
 */
private $right;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
 * @ORM\Column(name="root", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $root;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeParent
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
private $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Page", mappedBy="parent")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"left" = "ASC"})
 */
private $children;
```

And a `slug` field which reflected the hierarchy:

```
/**
 * @var string $slug
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 * @Gedmo\Slug(handlers={
 *      @Gedmo\SlugHandler(class="Gedmo\Sluggable\Handler\TreeSlugHandler", options={
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="parentRelationField", value="parent"),
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="separator", value="/")
 *      })
 * }, fields={"title"})
 */
private $slug;
```

Isn't this what you're looking for?